# Java: Embedded Equals Statements in While Loop

Tags: java, apache, while-loop, opennlp

I was wondering if someone could explain to me what the line of code below does?

`while((sample = samples.read()) != null)`

Does it first set `sample` equal to the next line of `samples`, and then check to make sure it's not empty?

This is more a general question, but if anyone has a good tutorial for OpenNLP, I would really appreciate that, as well.

Here is the method in its entirety:

`public static Dictionary buildNGramDictionary(ObjectStream samples, int cutoff) throws IOException {`

```
    NGramModel ngramModel = new NGramModel();
    POSSample sample;

    while((sample = samples.read()) != null) {
        String[] words = sample.getSentence();
        if (words.length > 0)
            ngramModel.add(new StringList(words), 1, 1);
    }

    ngramModel.cutoff(cutoff, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return ngramModel.toDictionary(true);
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what it does. The `=` operation, apart from setting the LHS, evaluates to the value of the RHS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evaluation of the expression is dictated by [operator precedence](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.7).
The expression inside the brackets `(sample = samples.read())` is evaluated first because the `()` brackets have a higher precedence than the `!=`

Answer (score 3):

1. it assigns the return value of `samples.read()` to the `sample` variable
2. it verifies whether `sample` is not null and only then executes the body of the while-loop